# Requirejs and avoiding polluting the global scope

Tags: javascript, module, requirejs

I suppose that I don't understand Require.js very well, so I wanted to ask why I can change firstName and lastName like in the example below (globally).

Shouldn't Require.js do stuff about avoiding polluting the global scope? I'm just providing the interface for creating an object, not for changing it's content. Thanks a lot.

```
// someModule.js
define([], function() {
    function Employee(firstName, lastName) {
        this.firstName = firstName;
        this.lastName = lastName;        
    }

    Employee.prototype.getName = function() {
        return this.firstName = ' ' = this.lastName;
    }

    return {
        createEmployee: function(fName, lName) {
            return new Employee(fName, lName);
        };
    };
});

// main.js
require(['jquery', 'someModule'], function($, someModule) {
    $(function() {
        var x = someModule.createEmployee('John', 'Doe');
        document.write(x.getName() + '<br>');
        x.firstName = 'Some other name';
        x.lastName = 'Some other surname';
        document.write(x.getName());
    });
});
```

And the output is: 
John Doe 
Some other name Some other surname

Comment: Better to post your code rather than a link to an image.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you're confusing global leaks with visibility of properties.  `firstName` and `lastName` aren't *leaked* - they're just publicly accessible and modifiable (mutable). If you want to hide them, you could do something like this:

```
function Employee(firstName, lastName) {    
    this.getFirstName = function () { return firstName; };
    this.getLastName = function () { return lastName; };
}

Employee.prototype.getName = function () {
     return this.getFirstname() + ' ' + this.getLastName();
};
```

Comment: The link has changed for [Understanding JavaScript OOP](http://killdream.github.io/2011/10/09/understanding-javascript-oop.html)

Comment: Both links are now dead and I can't find a mirror, so removed it :(

Comment: A cached copy of the post is available [here](http://web.archive.org/web/20131120224629/http://killdream.github.io/2011/10/09/understanding-javascript-oop.html).

Answer (score 1):

you don't polute any global scope here - your code runs inside anonymous function (closure) and nothing is bind to the window global object - so it's fine.

Answer (score 1):

Your created objects have properties, "firstName" and "lastName". Your code did nothing to prevent modifications to those properties.

In newer JavaScript implementations, there are ways to do that, but Requirejs isn't going to do it automatically (at least not without a significant redesign or enhancement project).

Specifically, the [`defineProperty`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/defineProperty) method lets you make read-only properties. Now, that will prevent *all* code from modifying the properties. If you want properties that are under control of the object, you can use a technique like what @c24w suggests in another answer.

Comment: Can you give me notes how to protect attributes of Employees from direct access? Thanks.

Comment: Setting the `writable` key to false when using `defineProperty` or `defineProperties` is a good solution (if backwards-compatibility isn't an issue).